# Get mysql SUM after mathematical operation

Tags: mysql, sum

Here is a portion of my query

```
(SUM(dr.drv)/100)*
  (st.suppliers1_value+st.suppliers2_value+st.suppliers3_value+st.suppliers4_value)
```

This will generate multiple rows. I want to get SUM of all of them. I tried

```
SUM(SUM(dr.drv)/100)*
  (st.suppliers1_value+st.suppliers2_value+st.suppliers3_value+st.suppliers4_value)
  as total drv_amount
```

But it's throwing an error. Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT SUM(dr.tickets_sold) as tickets_total_amount,
  SUM(dr.drv) as drv_total_amount,
  FORMAT(((SUM(dr.drv)/100) * (st.suppliers1_value+st.suppliers2_value+st.suppliers3_value+st.suppliers4_value) ),2 ) as supplier_commission,
  FORMAT(((SUM(dr.drv)/100) * st.exhibitor_value),2) as exhibitor_commission,
  FORMAT(((SUM(dr.drv)/100) * st.circuit_value),2) as distributer_commission,
  FORMAT(((SUM(dr.drv)/100) * (st.suppliers1_value+st.suppliers2_value+st.suppliers3_value+st.suppliers4_value)+((SUM(dr.drv)/100) * st.circuit_value )),2) as film_hire_total
FROM com_pro_dr as dr
INNER JOIN com_pro_ratecard_rates AS rt
  ON (dr.movie_id=rt.movie_id and
      dr.theater_id=rt.theater_id and
      dr.showtime_id=rt.showtime_id and
      dr.category_id=rt.category_id and
      dr.applied_date = rt.date_apply)
INNER JOIN com_pro_ratecard as rc ON (rc.id=rt.ratecard_id)
INNER JOIN com_pro_movie as m ON (m.id=dr.movie_id)
INNER JOIN com_pro_theater as t ON (t.id=dr.theater_id)
INNER JOIN com_pro_share as st ON (st.id=rc.share_id)
INNER JOIN com_pro_theater_dr as td ON (td.theater_id=dr.theater_id)
INNER JOIN com_pro_circuit as c ON (c.id =td.circuit_id)
WHERE 1
```

Comment: you need a (another?) GROUP BY for the 2nd SUM, and posting the whole query always helps

Comment: This is because you have muliple rows of st.suppliers1_value, st.suppliers2_value, st.suppliers3_value, st.suppliers4_value. Do you want to sum those first?

Comment: can you post the whole query in sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(val)
FROM
(
  SELECT (SUM(dr.drv)/100)*
    (st.suppliers1_value+st.suppliers2_value+st.suppliers3_value+st.suppliers4_value)
    AS val
  /* the rest of your current query */
) AS a
```